# Finding Integrable Function That Satisfy Given 3 Equation

Tags: integration, approximation, integral-equations

For my research, I am trying to find an integrable function $K_n$ over $[0,1]$ that satisfies following equations:

$\int_0^1 K_n (t,x_0)dt=1$

$\int_0^1 t. K_n (t,x_0)dt=x_0$

$\int_0^1 t^2 . K_n (t,x_0)dt=(x_0)^2$

I tried different functions (mostly standart and continuous ones) but none of them is useful for me. Any help or guidance be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I would start by writing the first equation in terms of the antiderivative of $K_n$. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this way to get one. Let
$$ K_n(t,x_0)=a(t-x_0)^2+b(t-x_0)+c $$
which means $K_n$ is quadratic. Then solving $a,b,c$ from
$$ \int_0^1 K_n (t,x_0)dt=1,\int_0^1 t K_n (t,x_0)dt=x_0, \int_0^1 t^2 K_n (t,x_0)dt=(x_0)^2$$
gives
$$ a= 30 \left(6 x_0^2-6 x_0+1\right),b= 36 \left(10 x_0^3-15
   x_0^2+7x_0-1\right),c= 9 \left(20 x_0^4-40x_0^3+28
   x_0^2-8x_0+1\right). $$
So
$$ K_n(t,x_0)=\cdots. $$

Comment: Xpaul thanks for your answer! It helped really much :)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it is helpful.

Comment: If you wanted more degrees of this sort of pattern, I'd consider using Legendre polynomials as the "basis pieces" instead of $(t-x_0)^n$, since the integral values are known and simple.

Comment: This function is enough for my problem. Moreover, if I have a positive function it smootly better. So that What if the case $K_n(t,x_0)>0$ for all t in $[0,1]$